Is gitlab merge request global id auto increment?
I can use gitlab merge request's API to list merge requests, and find that mr's id behaves auto increment. But I cannot find any document about this feature.

In gitlab source code, this filed is just a integer.
CREATE TABLE merge_requests (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    target_branch character varying NOT NULL,
    source_branch character varying NOT NULL,
    ...


It is indeed an increasing sequence, implemented here.
Lines 13520-13527:
CREATE SEQUENCE merge_requests_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
    
ALTER SEQUENCE merge_requests_id_seq OWNED BY merge_requests.id;

And line 22160:
ALTER TABLE ONLY merge_requests ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('merge_requests_id_seq'::regclass);

